# How can I create this CSS/SVG animation for a website?

Tags: javascript, css, performance, animation, svg

I've been tasked for doing some UX stuff for a new website (using Vue.js and SASS w/Bourbon), pretty similar to what https://stripe.com/connect does here:

[image]

So the question is how is this done? What technologies do I need to use? Is it just SVG and CSS? If so how is the SVG manipulated and what sort of SVG would I need the designer to make and what sort of CSS properties do I need to use to manipulate those elements?

A separate (but related) question would be, how can I achieve the fluidity and performance they have here? It's so silky smooth to interact with!

Comment: I'm not asking for code that "just" works, I'm asking for information. I'm not asking anyone to do the work for me, I am asking on guidance on how to go about doing the work myself. Would appreciate you and anyone who downvoted, just because you don't know the answer does not mean it to be a bad question. Perhaps what you were trying to say is that if there is no code that is shown along with the question, then it is a bad question for you? @PerHenrikJakobsson

Comment: @PerHenrikJakobsson Perhaps you should practice what you preach. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46324286/how-to-write-source-outside-of-xcode-and-have-it-compiled-by-xcode - hypocrite much my friend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I did it is to create an SVG file with any and all imagines, sections, icons, etc.. you will need, even if they overlap, and set them to have an opacity of zero so that you are left with the default version of what users will see first.

1. Make sure you name all SVG elements correctly and something that's easy to remember and group them according to how they will be animated. Group anything that will be animated together, together.
2. Set the elements that will be animated to have an opacity of zero.
3. Copy the SVG code and paste it directly into the HTML file.
4. With CSS target each ID and give them the animation you want.

This is just an example:

```
.first svg {
    #Tool {
      visibility: hidden;
    }
    #Tool-ON {
      @include transition(ease-in 0.5s);
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
```

If the HTML element has the `.first` class in place then the SVG will change according to the properties in the class. Fairly simple, but with this basic idea you can have a pretty cool animation of an image depending on user input.